# Ember not updating query parameters when calling transitionToRoute() right after

Tags: ember.js

In my application, I have an overall controller that manages state for a portion of the application, called `SimpleSearch`.

Within `SimpleSearch`, I have multiple `SimpleSearchOption`s, that display a list of choices to a user.

A user can select an option, and that selection is an action that is called from the view, that bubbles up to the `SimpleSearchOptionController`:

```
App.SimpleSearchOptionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
//....
    select: function (option) {
        option.queryName = this.get('queryName');
        this.get('simpleSearch').setSelection(option);
        this.set('selectedOption', option);
        this.set('hasSelectedOption', true);
        this.send('transitionToNextOption');
    },
//....
```

This action calls `this.get('simpleSearch').setSelection(option);`, which registers the selection with the `SimpleSearchController`:

```
App.SimpleSearchController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
//....
    setSelection: function (option) {
        this.set(option.queryName, option.value);
        this.get('selectedOptions').set(option.queryName, option.value);
        this.get('model').notifyPropertyChange('selectedOptions');
        this.checkIfAllOptionsSelected();
    },
//....
```

The important line in there is: `this.set(option.queryName, option.value);`.

After it registers the selection, it moves to the next option, and if there isn't one, it skips to the results of the search.  That is called from `this.send('transitionToNextOption');`

```
App.SimpleSearchOptionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
//....
    transitionToNextOption: function () {
        var nextOptionId = parseInt(this.get("id")) + 1;
        var numOfOptions = this.get('simpleSearch.numOfOptions');
        if (nextOptionId < numOfOptions) {
            this.transitionToRoute('simpleSearchOption', nextOptionId);
        }
        else {
            this.transitionToRoute('simpleSearchResults');
        }
    },
//....
```

In `setSelection()` above, the line `this.set(option.queryName, option.value);` is setting a query parameter's value.  This only works correctly, and the url gets updated accordingly for all options, *when I'm not transitioning to a different route*.

If I comment out the lines:

```
else {
    this.transitionToRoute('simpleSearchResults');
}
```

Setting the property (`this.set(option.queryName, option.value);`) actually has the side effect of Ember updating the query parameter in the URL, which is my intent.  If I include that line, and transition to a different route *after* setting that variable, the query parameter is not updated.

I was stepping through Ember's code, but I can't quite follow how it handles this.  It continues into `_doTransition()`, and I've noticed that the transition to the route 'simpleSearchResults' always happens before the queryParams are passed through.

How do I get Ember to update the query parameter before it transitions to 'simpleSearchResults'?

Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by wrapping the transition in an [`Ember.run.next()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_next) function:

```
transitionToNextOption: function () {
    var nextOptionId = parseInt(this.get("id")) + 1;
    var numOfOptions = this.get('simpleSearch.numOfOptions');
    if (nextOptionId < numOfOptions) {
        this.transitionToRoute('simpleSearchOption', nextOptionId);
    }
    else {
        var self = this;
        Ember.run.next(function() { self.transitionToRoute('simpleSearchResults'); });
    }
},
```

I'm assuming, but have not verified, that Ember was queuing up the action to transition to 'simpleSearchResults', and handles the query parameters similarly.  Perhaps the transition to a different route was somehow interrupting or overwriting the query parameter being written to the URL.